# Type conflict when passing StateSpec to MapWithState

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am getting the error message:

```
type mismatch; found:
org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[TCPKey,TCPValue,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[TCPValue],Option[Int]]
required: org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec[TCPKey.type, TCPValue.type, ?, ?]
```

in Eclipse, and cannot run my Scala Application as a result

I have tried other examples using "primitive" classes in my mapping function input for StateSpec and everything works properly, but once I use my predefined classes (TCPKey and TCPValue are defined in separate files), as below.

```
case class TCPKey(src: Entity, dst: Entity)
case class Entity(IP: Seq[Byte], Port: Int)
case class TCPValue(syn: Boolean, fin: Boolean, seq: Long, src: Entity, payload: Array[Byte]) /*I know this is mutable but I don't think that results in the problem above*/
```

I tried searching for a solution online but because the word "type" is so generic, and this is a rather niche case (using custom classes for SparkStreaming) is a not-so-popular language I did not manage to make much headway.

Really hope that a Scala/SparkStreaming expert can help! Thanks in advance!

Consulted https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions and looked at both SparkStreaming guides and Scala Documentation (I'm using Scala 2.11.8)

Comment: Can you please show us how you try to instantiate your `StateSpec`? Add the code.

Comment: Apologies, my workstation can't be accessed from home, and hence I couldn't get to type out the code. Turns out it was a silly bug where I returned Some(TCPKey, TCPValue) instead of Some(key, value) as I intended to. I only found out when I typed out the full code (workstation is disconnected from Internet), naming my types explicitly (so you did help :D). Sorry for the trouble, and may I just say I read your article on asyncified.io and am a big fan, you helped me a lot with starting out with SparkStreaming. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you, that was exactly the purpose in which it was made for :)